# CSS3 background is not repeating

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that the background "backgroundmain.png" WILL NOT repeat no matter what I do... I have tried adding more divs to contain everything in the body, but still no luck... I need the "backgroundmain.png" to fully repeat to cover the content at the bottom of the page.

P.S. I feel it may be a issue with all the divs being used, I just cant pin point it, so I am asking for a fresh set of eyes.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MetLoop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defaults.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
</head>


<body>
<!--Last Updated 1/14/17-->

<div id="back">

<nav class="header">
    <ul>
        <li style="margin-left: 15%"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Services">Our Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Map">Interactive Weather Map</a></li>
        <li style="float:right; margin-right: 15%"><a href="#Login">Log In</a></li>
        <li style="float:right;"><a href="#Signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="background">

    <div class="main">


        <!-- LOCAL WEATHER -->
        <div class="localweather">
            <p id="zipcode">Please enter your zip code to view today's local weather</p>
            <br>
            <form>
                <input type="number" name="Zip Code"> <br> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>



        </div>  

    <!-- VIDEO NEWSLETTER -->
        <div class="newsletter">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mXkPhOh5kKQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>


    <!-- TWITTER FEED -->
        <div class="feed">
            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="300" data-height="814" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/MetLoop">Tweets by MetLoop</a>
        </div>

    <!-- 7 DAY FORECAST -->
        <div class="weekweather">
            <p>Please enter your zip code above to view an accurate 7 day forecast</p>


        </div>

        <!-- LIVE RADAR MAP -->
        <div class="radar">

            <img src="images/usaweather.gif">


        </div>


    </div>

</div>






</body>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
</html>
```

================================================================================

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#back {
    background-image: url("images/backgroundmain.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

/*Navigation Bar*/
nav {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 48px;
    text-align: center;

}

ul {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
}


li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 125%;
    }
/*END NAV*/

/*Body Info*/
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url("images/backgroundmain.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 48px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*Local Weather*/
.localweather {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    background-image: url("images/weatherphoto.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12%;
}

#zipcode {
    font-family: 'Open Sans'; 
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

/*NEWSLETTER*/
.newsletter {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 26%;
    top: 2%;
}

/*TWITTER FEED*/

.feed {
    position: absolute;
    height: 85%;
    width: 20%;
    left: 78%;
    top: 2%;
}

/*7 DAY FORECAST*/

.weekweather {
    background-image: url("images/week.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 75%;
    height: 29%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;

}

/*RADAR MAP*/

.radar {
    background-image: url("images/backgroundmain.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 90%;
}

.radar img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The background on `#back` is repeating, but isn't showing up because that element is 0px height. It is 0px height because of the absolute positioning of it's children. If you assign a height to `#back`, you can see it is repeating. The solution would be to either assign a height to `#back` or rework your layout to reposition things so they maintain layout on the page and give `#back` a non-zero height.

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#back {
    background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
  min-height: 500vh;
}

/*Navigation Bar*/
nav {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 48px;
    text-align: center;

}

ul {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
}


li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 125%;
    }
/*END NAV*/

/*Body Info*/
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url("images/backgroundmain.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 48px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*Local Weather*/
.localweather {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    background-image: url("images/weatherphoto.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12%;
}

#zipcode {
    font-family: 'Open Sans'; 
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

/*NEWSLETTER*/
.newsletter {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 26%;
    top: 2%;
}

/*TWITTER FEED*/

.feed {
    position: absolute;
    height: 85%;
    width: 20%;
    left: 78%;
    top: 2%;
}

/*7 DAY FORECAST*/

.weekweather {
    background-image: url("images/week.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 75%;
    height: 29%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;

}

/*RADAR MAP*/

.radar {
    background-image: url("images/backgroundmain.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 90%;
}

.radar img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>MetLoop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defaults.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
</head>


<body>
<!--Last Updated 1/14/17-->

<div id="back">

<nav class="header">
    <ul>
        <li style="margin-left: 15%"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Services">Our Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Map">Interactive Weather Map</a></li>
        <li style="float:right; margin-right: 15%"><a href="#Login">Log In</a></li>
        <li style="float:right;"><a href="#Signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="background">

    <div class="main">


        <!-- LOCAL WEATHER -->
        <div class="localweather">
            <p id="zipcode">Please enter your zip code to view today's local weather</p>
            <br>
            <form>
                <input type="number" name="Zip Code"> <br> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>



        </div>  

    <!-- VIDEO NEWSLETTER -->
        <div class="newsletter">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mXkPhOh5kKQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>


    <!-- TWITTER FEED -->
        <div class="feed">
            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="300" data-height="814" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/MetLoop">Tweets by MetLoop</a>
        </div>

    <!-- 7 DAY FORECAST -->
        <div class="weekweather">
            <p>Please enter your zip code above to view an accurate 7 day forecast</p>


        </div>

        <!-- LIVE RADAR MAP -->
        <div class="radar">

            <img src="images/usaweather.gif">


        </div>


    </div>

</div>






</body>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
</html>
```